# How to autoplay Spotify playlist URI?

Tags: iframe, spotify

Currently developing a website that embeds a spotify playlist with its URI as so: 
"https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:playlist:4hYaUylcBHW9Se152NoIy0"
I'm wondering if there's an autoplay parameter that allows the playlist to play automatically when the web page is loaded ?

It seems like this idea (to have an autoplay parameter) has been proposed before in these posts: (But none of them have gotten enough votes to succeed) 
https://community.spotify.com/t5/Closed-Ideas/All-Platforms-Autoplay-Parameter-for-Spotify-URIs/idi-p/1320044
The post above mentions doing something like this: 
spotify:user:Username:playlist:PlaylistCode:autoplay:true
(would play it just as you click on the link)
spotify:user:Username:playlist:PlaylistCode:autoplay:false
(would not play it, you would need to press the play button)
This post (http://routenote.com/blog/how-to-embed-and-customise-spotify-in-websites-and-blogs/comment-page-1/#comment-428929) suggests that you can add parameters to view the cover art or change the color of your playlists (didn't work when I tried that), so I'm wondering if there's a similar parameter for autoplay? This post ([Spotify Play Button - autoplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293017/spotify-play-button-autoplay)) says it doesn't, but this was from 2012.

And if there is no autoplay parameter, is there a way to autoplay a Spotify playlist via the Spotify Web API? According to this Stack Overflow post ([Update on Spotify API not allowing auto play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28985613/update-on-spotify-api-not-allowing-auto-play)) , there was a glitch with autoplaying Spotify tracks, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in way to autoplay Spotify playlists?

Lastly, if the Spotify Web API does not allow playlists to autoplay, do others know of the platforms that allow that? This post mentions Soundcloud and Vimeo as other options: [Spotify Play Button - autoplay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293017/spotify-play-button-autoplay)

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The playlists don't seem to have an autoplay option

If the playlist is embedded in you own website you can click the play button using javascript.

```
document.querySelector('[title="Play"]').click()
```

Comment: it seems not working

Comment: cors stops you from being able to access the contents of an iframe from a different origin

Answer (score 0):

You can open and autoplay any track or playlist using **Spotify URI** and **:play** switch at the end of URI.

Working examples:

1. Open and autoplay playlist:
   **spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1DZ06evO1SeOS4:play**
2. Open and autoplay album:
   **spotify:album:11H3JkQiYm6ydXZuDWs4RO:play**
3. Open and autoplay track:
   **spotify:track:2WjO8esLemTbsqMEak07B9:play**

Those URI's are handled by Spotify app (works for PWA in the browser, Desktop apps and phone apps as well as long as Spotify app is installed).

Currently there are no parameters available to autoplay anything in Spotify using URL's.
For example those URL's will open an album but WILL NOT auto play it:

```
https://open.spotify.com/album/5RnExdPm0cenE3Tx2wWQss?play
https://open.spotify.com/album/5RnExdPm0cenE3Tx2wWQss?play=1
https://open.spotify.com/album/5RnExdPm0cenE3Tx2wWQss?play=true
https://open.spotify.com/album/5RnExdPm0cenE3Tx2wWQss?autoplay=1
```

Few years back there was an option to autoplay embeded playlist in an iframe using **?autoplay=1** parameter:

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/37i9dQZF1DZ06evO1SeOS4?autoplay=1" width="300" height="900" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

but Spotify, being concerned about iframe hijacking on websites that abused this functionality, decided to disable autoplaying thus it is not working anymore.