# Spotify iframe autoplay and loop

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed, spotify

I have trouble making this spotify playlist embed autoplay and loop:

`<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/1AY38eMsiNv8VCKP59wBDt" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media" loop="true"></iframe>`

Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: The answer given to [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566177/how-to-autoplay-spotify-playlist-uri appears to say there is no way (within a iframe) but that answer was given 7 months ago so things may have changed.